# HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL; error in creating a login page

Tags: javascript, web-services

```
<head>
    <title>Login form</title>
</head>enter image description here
<body>
    <form method="post" action="MySQLConnect">        
    Username :<input type="text" name="user" /><br/><br/>
    Password :<input type="password" name="pass" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
</body>
```

I'm getting this error please help me in resolving this.

[image]

Comment: <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MySQLConnect</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>MySQLConnect</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MySQLConnect</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MySQLConnect</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>

Comment: Where is error? Your link is only netbeans photo. No error in there.

Comment: when i open the link it is showing..... HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL


type Status report

messageHTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

descriptionThe specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.                                                                                                                                         Thank You!